# Ubuntu Server 16.04 iSCSI to ESXi

Tags: 16.04, server, iscsi, esx

I've recently moved my storage out to a SAN which runs Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS.  The SAN and ESXi box each have two NICs: one for management, and one for iSCSI.  The iSCSI NICs are 10Gbps and configured statically as 10.11.1.1 on the SAN and 10.11.1.2 on ESXi.  Both NICs can see each other and receive replies from ping on both sides.  In the vSphere client, I've added the 10Gbps NIC on the ESXi system as a VMkernel interface and configured it appropriately.  However, when I go to Add Storage, no targets are available under Select Disk/LUN.

Here are the steps taken to setup the SAN:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade  
$ sudo apt install iscsitarget iscsitarget-dkms  
$ sudo sed -i -e "s/ISCSITARGET_ENABLE=false/ISCSITARGET_ENABLE=true/" /etc/default/iscsitarget  
$ sudo cat >> /etc/iet/ietd.conf <<EOF  


Target iqn.2014-11.home.lab.san:storage00  
  Lun 0 Path=/dev/sda1,Type=fileio      # path to storage block device RAID6 array  
  initiator-address 10.11.1.2           # static IP for esxi.lab.home iSCSI 10Gbps nic  


EOF  
$ sudo systemctl restart iscsitarget.service  
$ sudo ietadm --op show --tid=1  
Wthreads=8  
Type=0  
QueuedCommands=32  
NOPInterval=0  
NOPTimeout=0
```

Any suggestions?  My suspicion was doing something wrong in the SAN setup, but all info I've found online shows the same setup steps.

Edit: I've posted some screenshots of the adapter settings on imgur (https://i.stack.imgur.com/meaCg.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to manually add the LUN for ESXi to see it exposed.

```
$ sudo ietadm --op new --tid=3 --params Name=iqn.2014-11.home.lab.san:storage03  
$ sudo ietadm --op new --tid=3 --lun=0 --params Path=/dev/sda1,Type=blockio
```